# Fading scroll bars in Atom Editor

Tags: atom-editor

I would like to customise my Atom Editor so that all scroll bars would fade out when their parent is not hovered with the cursor. Trying to accomplish this, I added the following lines to my `styles.less` stylesheet:

```
atom-text-editor.editor {
    .horizontal-scrollbar, .vertical-scrollbar {
        opacity: 0.2;
        transition: opacity 250ms;
    }
    .scroll-view:hover .horizontal-scrollbar {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .scroll-view:hover .vertical-scrollbar {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

This works very well for the main editor view. When two or more panes are present, the scroll bar of the hovered file is shown in full colour while the other(s) fade out. Unfortunately this applies only to files and not to the tree view. How would I adapt the code above to include the scroll bars of the tree view as well as the ones of the files?  I am using the Atom Material UI theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved by adding the following code to `styles.less`

```
// fading scrollbars when pane not hovered
.pane:not(:hover) {
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        &-thumb {
            background-color: rgba(68, 169, 249, 0.3);
        }
    }
}
```